# Reproducing MomentCam's filtering with fragment shader on OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I'm trying to reproduce the high-quality of MomentCam's filtering with a fragment shader for my 2D images, but so far, i could not find the right way in order to something similar to this:

http://technode.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/14.jpg http://img.1mobile.com/market/screenshot/0c/com.eagleinc.comiccamera/0.png http://img.1mobile.com/market/screenshot/8f/com.liyuanqin.momentcam.share.aviary.editor/0.png

I'm using this to capture the user photo with the device camera and then trying to use it as a texture on my game (the player's head). Does anyone have an example GLSL fragment shader with similar behavior? Most i can find are just sobel edge or hatch, and they look like crap when using with people faces.

Comment: Whoever vote to close, can you please be polite and explain your reasons? The question is pretty relevant and is OK with the rules.

Comment: I didn't vote. But what people are normally looking for in questions is that you show what you tried, and the specific problems you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that they may be using face detection to detect where the face is and applying a filter only to that area.  Something like a [Canny edge detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) might be sufficient if you can isolate the face and tune the algorithm specifically for faces without worrying about the rest of the scene.